# Why am I unable to update the email address in android?

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-contentresolver

```
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.clear();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(Data._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)})
            .withValue(Email.DATA, "somebody1@android.com")
            .build());

    try 
    {
        context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    }
```

The logs don't show me anything. But the email is not updated. Does anyone know why?

The ops converted to string is as follows:

```
[mType: 2, mUri: content://com.android.contacts/data, mSelection: _id=?, mExpectedCount: null, mYieldAllowed: false, mValues: data1=somebody1@android.com, mValuesBackReferences: null, mSelectionArgsBackReferences: null]
```

Comment: have you tried using Log.d('tag',VALUEasSTRING); to check your values?

Comment: Which value do you mean? The id? If so yes

Comment: actually all the values, but sounds like you already tried this

Comment: I'm having this issue too.  No matter what I do, it doesn't seem to update.  My `ContentProviderOperation` looks exactly the same.

Comment: Where is id coming from ? My guess is it could be something else like a raw contact ID, meaning that the selection would be empty and thus no update would be performed. @Jonah

Comment: @desseim I didn't see your comment before.  I'm getting it from `Entity.DATA_ID` when querying in the first place.  I've started my own question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21594024/278899

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a `try` without a `catch`, which may explain why you don't see any error in the logs.

Second, from what I can see in the documentation, I think you should better write it this way:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.clear();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", 
                       new String[] {String.valueOf(id)})
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, "somebody1@android.com")
        .build());

try {
    context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use inside withValue not string, but array of strings.

```
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emails)
```

where

```
String[] emails = {"Email Name<somebody1@android.com>"};
```